# How to define ESS key bindings correctly in Aquamacs?

Tags: macos, r, emacs

I made a switch to Mac and had to ditch my favorite R Editor (Notepad++). Now I am trying to learn Emacs. The learning curve is steep, but this seems like *the* editor for R once I learn to use it. I am using OS X 10.8.3 and Aquamacs 2.4

I am trying to set custom key bindings following excellent tips from these SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901198/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-and-tips-for-ess-r),[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/what-are-some-good-references-advice-for-learning-emacs-speaks-statistics-with),[3](https://superuser.com/questions/214295/emacs-how-to-choose-good-custom-key-bindings).

If I copy this command to preferences.el file, Aquamacs opens without complaining and the command works:

```el
(global-set-key [C-tab] 'other-window)
```

However, if I try to set one of the following options:

```el
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C .") 'ess-eval-paragraph)
(define-key ess-mode-map [C-.] 'ess-eval-paragraph)
(define-key ess-mode-map "\C-." 'ess-eval-paragraph)
```

Aquamacs opens and complains, but the command works:

> An error has occurred while loading `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Preferences.el (or .elc)':
>
> Symbol's value as variable is void: ess-mode-map
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

I want to use Ctrl + . to run paragraphs of R code/buffer to R. Obviously I am doing something wrong. As I am a complete newbie to Mac and Emacs, this feels overwhelming. What is going on and how can fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify `ess-mode-map` before it exists. It doesn't exist until ess (specifically ess-mode) has been loaded. So something like the following should work:

```el
(eval-after-load "ess-mode"
  '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'ess-eval-paragraph))
```

EDIT: note that `C-.` is not in the ascii character set, so the `"\C-."` string will not work. You have to use the `(kbd "C-.")` form instead. The string would work for other combinations, like `"\C-a"` (not that you should bind this to C-a). See the [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this piece of code it complains: "error: Invalid modifier in string". Maybe the code is not entirely correct?

Comment: Hmm. This is weird. If I define the key binding either as [C-.] or (kbd "C ."), the program starts normally without complaining, but the keyboard shortcut is not defined.

Comment: Following works: `(eval-after-load "ess-mode" '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'ess-eval-paragraph))`. I don´t know why the other key binding opinions do not work. Maybe I did something wrong somewhere or maybe it´s because of my Norwegian keyboard. Could you update this alternative to your answer, please? I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I figured out why my first answer didn't work and added the explanation above.

Comment: Say that I want the same key binding, but with different commands,  for .tex  and .rnw files. Is still correct to use: `eval-after-load` or should I use hooks to change the command when the buffer mode/file changes?